# select or show certain rows in combobox mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have table named `services` where all orthodontic services are stored. The following is the list of data stored in the services table:

```
Extract
Cleaning
Jacket
Upper teeth braces
lower teeth braces
upper and lower teeth braces
```

I want these services to be stored/populated in `cmbBraces`. However, then it shows all services: I only want three particular services to be populated in `cmbBraces` (`Upper teeth braces`, `lower teeth braces`, `upper and lower teeth braces`).

This is my code that populates `cmbBraces`:

```
 MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim ds6 As New DataSet
        Dim da6 As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt6 As New DataTable
        Dim cmd10 As New MySqlCommand

        With cmd10
            .Connection = MySqlConn
            .CommandText = "SELECT Service_Name FROM services"
        End With
        da6.SelectCommand = cmd10
        dt6.Clear()
        da6.Fill(ds6)
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt6 = ds6.Tables(0)


        For Each dtRow As DataRow In dt6.Rows
            cmbBracess.Items.Add(dtRow(0))
        Next
        MySqlConn.close()
```

Comment: Your query takes all the rows from the database table. If you have another field in that table that differentiate between elements in the Service_Name column you could use that field to build an appropriate WHERE clause.Could you add to your question all the columns present in the services table?

Comment: Thanks @Steve I got your point! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most correct way to do what you require is adding another column to your services table. Suppose to call this column IsBrace of type bit (it could have only two values 0 or 1)

Now you should set this column with the following values for each Services_Name

```
 Service_Name                             IsBrace
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 Extract                                  0
 Cleaning                                 0
 Jacket                                   0
 Upper teeth braces                       1
 lower teeth braces                       1
 upper and lower teeth braces             1
```

After this is in place, you could change your query to retrieve only the rows that have the `IsBrace` column set to 1

```
 .CommandText = "SELECT Service_Name FROM services WHERE IsBrace = 1"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! :)